# Combine output of jq onto single line per record output

Tags: jq

I currently have output from `jq` that looks like this:

```
1§
{"id":"1","name":"River Street , Clerkenwell","lastUpdate":"1601461560941"}
2§
{"id":"2","name":"Phillimore Gardens, Kensington","lastUpdate":"1601461560941"}
```

and I would like it join the output lines per record, i.e.:

```
1§{"id":"1","name":"River Street , Clerkenwell","lastUpdate":"1601461560941"}
2§{"id":"2","name":"Phillimore Gardens, Kensington","lastUpdate":"1601461560941"}
```

**Here is the sample input and current filter: https://jqplay.org/s/qBfGyriA5B**

If I use `-j` then I get everything on the same line, which is not what I want

```
1§{"id":"1","name":"River Street , Clerkenwell","lastUpdate":"1601461560941"}2§{"id":"2","name":"Phillimore Gardens, Kensington","lastUpdate":"1601461560941"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to use the `join` function by empty string on the created objects. Note that the object you are creating needs to converted to string type for it to work. Use the filter below with the `--raw-output/-r` mode

```
.stations.station[] + { lastUpdate: .stations."@lastUpdate" } | 
[ .id + "§", tostring ] | 
join("")
```

<sup>[jqplay demo](https://jqplay.org/s/4As0sJGyBd)</sup>